# Jquery check all select elements selectedIndex is 0

Tags: jquery, html-select, selector

I have a 4 select elements for a calendar range and I want to check if ALL of select elements chosen with the selector have the first option selected (selectedIndex is == 0). I'd even be ok with checking that the value of all of them isn't "" but nothing seems to be working.

```
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 ...
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Year</option>
 <option value="1950">1950</option>
 <option value="1951">1951</option
 ....
 <option value="2015">2015</option
</select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 ...
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Year</option>
 <option value="1950">1950</option>
 <option value="1951">1951</option
 ....
 <option value="2015">2015</option
</select>
```

So, I only want to get into my if statement if ALL of them have a selectedIndex == 0 or have a value of "".

Some of the things I've tried

```
if ( $( ".selCalendar" ).filter('option[value=""]').length )
{
 ...
}

if ( $(".selCalendar option[value='']" ).attr('selected', 'selected').length )
{
 ...
}

if( $( ".selCalendar option:selected" ).index() > 0)
{
 ...
}

if ( $(".selCalendar option:selected").length)
{
 ...
}
```

I have found answers on a single select with the first option selected but not checking all the selects.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `$(".selCalendar").each(function() {})` will loop through all selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Year</option>
 <option value="1950">1950</option>
 <option value="1951">1951</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 </select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
 <option value="">Year</option>
 <option value="1950">1950</option>
 <option value="1951">1951</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Check" id="myButton" />
```

**javascript**

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var isAllBlank = true;
    $(".selCalendar").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() !== "") {
            isAllBlank = false;   
        }
    });

    alert(isAllBlank);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vjtpd4vx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```js
var res = $(".selCalendar").is(function(i, el) {
  return el.selectedIndex === 0
});
// do stuff 
// if all `.selCalendar` `selectedIndex === 0` 
if (res) {
  alert("all `.selCalendar` `selectedIndex === 1`")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="startMonth" class="selCalendar">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="startYear" class="selCalendar">
  <option value="">Year</option>
  <option value="1950">1950</option>
  <option value="1951">1951</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select name="endMonth" class="selCalendar">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="endYear" class="selCalendar">
  <option value="">Year</option>
  <option value="1950">1950</option>
  <option value="1951">1951</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe .every() is supported in all browser versions and don't want to add a Polyfill. Also, I can't use something with a callback.

Comment: @BPercival _".every() is supported in all browser versions"_ Which browsers not supported  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every ?  _"can't use something with a callback"_ not appear at original Question ?

Comment: @BPercival See updated post, substituted `.is()` for `.every()` . can describe _"can't use something with a callback" _ ?

Comment: .every isn't supported in IE8. Thanks for the info on is()  though.  You are correct, I didn't say what I can't use in the question.  Should I have included everything that I can't use?  I also can't use an Ajax request to a server side php page that returns if all selects are at selectedIndex of 0.

Comment: @BPercival _"didn't say what I can't use in the question. Should I have included everything that I can't use?"_ Yes, if impleneted at `js` and would help resolve Question ? _"can't use an Ajax request "_ ? "Ajax" not appear at original Question ?